# Dropdownlist fills multiple times when postback, but I can't put it in !IsPostback

Tags: c#, webforms, radio-button, postback, dropdown

I have a problem I can't figure out. Hope you can help me.

I have an advanced search function, where I first have to choose if I want to search in menus or events by selecting a radiobutton. The problem is, that when I have chosen there is a postback, and I have to fill a dropdownlist with items.

It works fine, but if I search multiple times, the items are filled in again, because it's not in my `if(!IsPostback){...}` block, but I can't put it there, because there is a postback.

So how do I resolve this? I have tried to clear my items in different places, but that only results in the dropdownlist being empty. Here is some of my code:

```
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PnlMenu.Visible = false;
        PnlEvents.Visible = false;
        PnlResult.Visible = false;

        //søgemuligheder
        RblSearch.Items.Add(new ListItem("MENU", "1"));
        RblSearch.Items.Add(new ListItem("EVENTS", "2"));

        string _search = Request.QueryString["search"];
        DataTable dt = objsearch.Search(_search);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_search))
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
                {
                    if (RblSearch.SelectedValue == "1")
                    {
                        LitResult.Text += "<h4>Du har søgt på <span style='color: green;'>" + Session["search"].ToString() + "</span> - Der er " + dt.Rows.Count + " menuer, som matcher din søgning:</h4>";
                    }
                    if (RblSearch.SelectedValue == "2")
                    {
                        LitResult.Text += "<h4>Du har søgt på <span style='color: green;'>" + Session["search"].ToString() + "</span> - Der er " + dt.Rows.Count + " events, som matcher din søgning:</h4>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (RblSearch.SelectedValue == "1")
                    {
                        LitResult.Text += "<h4>Du har søgt på <span style='color: green;'>" + Session["search"].ToString() + "</span> - Der er " + dt.Rows.Count + " menu, som matcher din søgning:</h4>";
                    }
                    if (RblSearch.SelectedValue == "2")
                    {
                        LitResult.Text += "<h4>Du har søgt på <span style='color: green;'>" + Session["search"].ToString() + "</span> - Der er " + dt.Rows.Count + " event, som matcher din søgning:</h4>";
                    }
                }

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    LitResult.Text += "<div class='searchresult'><h3>" + dr["fldName"] + "</h3><img style='width: 55%;' src='../img/band/" + dr["fldImg"] + "' /></div>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LitResult.Text += "<h4>Du har søgt på <span style='color: red;'>" + Session["search"].ToString() + "</span> - Der er ingen resultater! Prøv igen!";
            }
        }
    }

    //DdlMenu.Items.Clear();
    //DdlEvents.Items.Clear();

    //Menu
    if (RblSearch.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        DdlMenu.Items.Add(new ListItem("- - - VÆLG MENU - - -", "0"));
        foreach (DataRow drmenu in objdiner.GetAllDinerCats().Rows)
        {
            DdlMenu.Items.Add(new ListItem(drmenu["fldName"].ToString(), drmenu["fldId"].ToString()));
        }
    }

    //Events
    TxtDatoFra.Attributes.Add("min", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    if (RblSearch.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        DdlEvents.Items.Add(new ListItem("- - - VÆLG TYPE - - -", "0"));
        foreach (DataRow drevent in objevent.GetAllEventKats().Rows)
        {
            DdlEvents.Items.Add(new ListItem(drevent["fldName"].ToString(), drevent["fldId"].ToString()));
        }
    }
}
protected void RblSearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RblSearch.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        PnlMenu.Visible = true;
        PnlEvents.Visible = false;
        DdlEvents.Items.Clear();
    }

    if (RblSearch.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        PnlEvents.Visible = true;
        PnlMenu.Visible = false;
        DdlMenu.Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use event handlers instead of `Page_Load`

Comment: Set dt to null before doing 2nd search.  The datatable is retaining the results from the 1st search.

Comment: @jdweng: nothing is retained from the previous search if it's not stored somewhere, for example in the Session. ASP.NET diosposes all objects at the end of the page's lifecycle, including controls and variables.

Comment: Yes but if you had a connection is the connection properly closing so it can be opened for the 2nd search.  And if they are closed, are you allowing enough time for the items to be completely closed.  And registering events with the operating system, are you un-registering the events with a '-='?

Comment: I have resolved it by clearing and filling my items in the bottom of the click event. But if you have a better way of doing it Tim, you tell me. I'm new at this and I don't know much about event handlers.